Python type annotations for functions that return a class
Consider the following code, which models the integers mod n:
def IntegersModN(n):
    class InternalClass:
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x % n
        def __add__(self, other):
            return self.__class__(self.x + other.x)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.x)
    return InternalClass

IntegersMod5 = IntegersModN(5)
print(IntegersMod5(4) + IntegersMod5(2)) # output: 1

It runs fine. But suppose I wanted to add type annotations to statically ensure that I never do something like:
IntegersMod4 = IntegersModN(4)
IntegersMod5 = IntegersModN(5)
print(IntegersMod4(1) + IntegersMod5(2)) # desired mypy error

I know it's probably not possible to statically check that the mods are equal, but I was hoping that at least there was a way to differentiate every class constructed by IntegersModN. In other words, I would like each call of IntegersModN to produce a new InternalClass that only allows adding two elements of itself. In particular, the following code should also throw a mypy error:
IntegersMod5_1 = IntegersModN(5)
IntegersMod5_2 = IntegersModN(5)
print(IntegersMod5_1(1) + IntegersMod5_2(2)) # desired mypy error

Is that possible? (I tried just adding Self annotations to the arguments in __add__(self, other), but that didn't seem to do anything. Using Python 3.13.) Additionally, if not possible in Python, what other programming languages is this possible in?


I know it's probably not possible to statically check that the mods are equal [...]

On the contrary, this is possible. You just need to change the way you define the classes:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
#                  vvvvvv `N` is defined here
class IntegersModN[N: int]:
    x: int
    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None: ...
    #                                     v Same type as above
    def __add__(self, other: IntegersModN[N]) -> Self:
        #                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Self` has similar effect
        return self.__class__(self.x + other.x)

class IntegersMod4(IntegersModN[Literal[4]]): ...
class IntegersMod5(IntegersModN[Literal[5]]): ...
#                               ^^^^^^^^^^ `N` is given a value here

# error: Unsupported operand types for + ("IntegersMod4" and "IntegersMod5")
IntegersMod4(1) + IntegersMod5(2)

(Inspecting the value of n at runtime is left as an exercise for the reader.)
This does not work for classes created dynamically with a function, like what you are currently doing, simply because their dynamicity is in sharp contrast with static type checking.

how is n actually provided to the class here? the value for self.x = x % n

That's a pretty big exercise for the reader to undertake. I think you should spell it out.

Added a link. The exercise should be much simpler now.
